# What short story features an alien blob in bed and a guy who became its lover?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to identify a short SF/Fantasy story of an alien blob lying on a bed in a room where this guy found it and became its lover.

Comment: Is this something you've actually read before, or just heard about? When did you read it? Was it part of an anthology or in a magazine? What language was it in? Did it seem to be aimed at any particular age group? Any detail, no matter how trivial it may seem, might help someone find this for you.

Comment: Does contact with the blob/amoeba cause euphoria but also painful rash, and does it end with the guy being absorbed by the blob because he becomes addicted to the contact? If so, I've run across the story in several anthologies; I'll see if it's in any of the ones I've got

Answer (score 7):

*[Oh, to Be a Blobel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh,_to_Be_a_Blobel!)* is a Philip K. Dick short story about humans interbreeding with blobs. The humans fought a war with the blobs which involved genetically engineering humans to be able to take the forms of the "Blobels", with the Blobels doing the same with their own people to impersonate humans.

The human and Blobel veterans were then unable to change back permanently, being forced to spend some portion of every day in the alternate form. They resolved the issue by interbreeding.

It could be the story you're after. Even if not, it's a good read, as is the case with most of Dick's work.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be *"How's the Night Life on Cissalda?"* by Harlan Ellison?  It's the story of Enoch Mirren, temponaut, who returns from his trip to an alternate earth:

> "When they unscrewed the time capsule, preparatory to helping temponaut
>   Enoch Mirren to disembark, they found him doing a disgusting thing
>   with a disgusting thing."

The story is in the Ellison collection [*Shatterday*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/416059.Shatterday)